# Azure AD - id_token not refreshing

Tags: jwt, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

I'm using AAD to lock down my azure web app and api.  I am calling `/.auth/me` to retrieve the authenticated user's tokens, and then using the `id_token` to authenticate the user to the api.  The `id_token` expires in 1 hour, which should be fine as you can call `/.auth/refresh` to get new tokens.  Issue is that "refresh" only seems to refresh `access_token` and `refresh_token`, not `id_token`.  Only way I can get a new `id_token` is if i open a fresh incognito and re-authenticate.

Any ideas on this?  `id_token` is acceptable to lock down an api, no?  `access_token` doesn't have claims on it so i'm interested in using `id_token`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, we can not use refresh_token to renew an id_token. If you want to refresh an id_token, we can just re-authenticate for the id_token.

And in my opinion, if the id_token is just be used for passing user identity in a standardized structure (JWT) then the backend will treat it as a plain JWT and ignore the expiry. It will assume the called is authenticated.

Comment: thanks for the feedback. i don't want to create an ever-living token as i'm using it for security. it sounds to me like i need to pass the access_token and the id_token; access_token for expiry purposes and id_token for claims. is that correct?

Comment: Talked to MSFT's product group and the "easy auth" of configuring on the azure web app is legacy and does not support the latest standards. as such, it will not work as I need it to. i need to implement my own authentication, such as using msal for angular